# Referencing and reading columns in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a table which is something like this -

```
Column1     Column2       Column3
V1          V1             10
V2          V2             20
V3          V1+V2          30
V4          V2+V3          50
V5          V5             10
V6          V1+V4          60
V7          V1+V5+V3       50
...         ...            ...
```

I'm trying to create another table which identifies the dependencies dynamically. So my result should look something like

```
Column1      Dependent1      Dependent2     Dependent3
V3            V1              V2             null
V4            V3              V2             null
V6            V1              V4             null
V7            V1              V5              V3
...           ...             ...             ...
```

Is there a way to reference the same table and read the dependencies in sql.

Using Postgres and sqlServer

Comment: Is the number of dependencies fixed? I mean do you know if three 'Dependent' columns are enough or do you need them to be generated automatically?

Comment: The dependencies are dynamic. But for sake of simplicity lets assume it to be 3 @PacoDePaco

Comment: To me this whole thing smells of a bad design - why do you store multiple values in one cell and why do you need the result in columns instead of rows? SQL is not designed to be good at such tasks.

Comment: @PacoDePaco, Strongly Agree. This is really some very bad design.

Comment: @ThatBeardTho : `sql server` or `psql`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using XML -

```
create table  SourceTable   ( Column1 varchar(10) , Column2 varchar(30) ,      Column3 int)
go

insert into SourceTable
select 'V1'    ,      'V1'           ,  10
union all select 'V2'    ,      'V2'           ,  20
union all select 'V3'    ,      'V1+V2'        ,  30
union all select 'V4'    ,      'V2+V3'        ,  50
union all select 'V5'    ,      'V5'           ,  10
union all select 'V6'    ,      'V1+V4'        ,  60
union all select 'V7'    ,      'V1+V5+V3'     ,  50


 create table temp (
     Column1  varchar(10)       , Column2 xml  
)

insert into temp
select Column1 ,   '<Col>' + REPLACE( Column2,'+' , '</Col><Col>' ) +     '</Col>'  from SourceTable 

 select * , t1.Column2.value('(/Col)[1]','varchar(10)')Dependent1,   
 t1.Column2.value('(/Col)[2]','varchar(10)') Dependent2  ,
 t1.Column2.value('(/Col)[3]','varchar(10)') Dependent3
 from temp as t1
```

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres:

```
select column1, 
       split_part(column2, '+', 1) as dependent1,
       split_part(column2, '+', 2) as dependent2,
       split_part(column2, '+', 3) as dependent3
from some_table;
```